# Symfony2 cached controller won't update

Tags: php, symfony, caching, controller

I'm quite new to PHP and have received some Symfony2 project to maintain. Now I've found out that when I update `foo.html.twig`, that page will not change until I perform the command `console c:c -e prod`. Until then the shown page will be `foo.html_.twig` (hence the underscore).

The problem is that I've changed a controller, let's say `BarController.php`, but the new added value in that controller does not work in the .twig file, I think because the `BarController_.php` did not get updated with the clear cache command. What did I do wrong here?

Edit:
As Nate says it's not Symfony that caches controllers, but at least I see that `BarController_.php` is much older than `BarController.php`, and it's the one with the underscore that does not have the newly added value.

Edit 2:
`BarController.php` and `BarController_.php` both reside in the same folder.

Comment: Symfony does not cache controllers.  Can you post more detailed info about your problem?

Comment: What is this underscore stuff about? You cannot name files with a trailing underscore.

Comment: @mblaettermann I wonder as well, I thought these were cached versions of the controllers. At least it is the same thing, but out of date.

Comment: Maybe it's an old backup then. I would move them out of the project directory. They should not be used anymore.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Apparently I was completely looking at the wrong places. It had nothing to do with caching at all.

Those underscored files appeared because of my hacky way of 'version control', which meant I copied a file I was going to edit, put '.old' after the filename so I had a backup. For some reason there was created an underscored file for these things.

The problem of not being able to read the getter's value was just a bug in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you need to clear cache by your own. You can try

```
rm -rf app/cache/prod/*
```

and don't forget to change rights.

Comment: This did not work, since the 'underscored controller' resides in the same folder as the right controller.